# Does mayer's equation change for two mole of ideal gases or is it remains same for any number of moles

Tags: thermodynamics, heat

*Mayer's Formula is given by: **Cp – Cv = R***
But is the relation remains same for two mole of ideal gas, or is it
***Cp - Cv = 2R***

As, far as i know the number of moles are cancelled out in the derivation.

∆H = ∆U + nR∆T
nCp∆T = nCv∆T +nR∆T
Cp - Cv = R   (remains same)

(***∆H*** is enthalpy change, ***∆U*** is internal energy change, ***n*** is no of moles, ***R*** is gas constant and ***∆T*** is change in temperature, ***Cp*** is molar specific heat capacity of an ideal gas at constant pressure, ***Cv*** is molar specific heat capacity of an ideal gas at constant volume )

Comment: Useful links for text and formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) // Use plain texts in CH SE titles. // For more, see [Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that dimension of $R, C_p, C_V$ is $\pu{J K-1 mol-1}$ and not  $\pu{J K-1}$.

[Molar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_heat_capacity) ($\pu{J K-1 mol-1}$) and [specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity) ($\pu{J K-1 kg-1}$) heat capacities are [intensive properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties), independent on scaling (amount of gas).

[Heat capacities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity) ($\pu{J K-1}$)  are [extensive properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties), proportional to scaling (amount of gas).